# Nginx get $request_uri after a certain point

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect certain requests to a cloudfront distro, and to do so I need to redirect to a different hostname with the first section of the `$request_uri` trimmed off. So:

```
 location /storage/multimedia/ {
    set $new_uri $request_uri # insert trim logic here 
                              # $new_uri is now multimedia/...

    return 301 https://d2joqwdayszh6j.cloudfront.net/$new_uri;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a capture and passing it to the redirection

```
location ^~ /storage/(multimedia.*) {
  return 301 https://d2joqwdayszh6j.cloudfront.net/$1;
}
```